# I am trying to use URL Rewrite

Tags: url, url-rewriting

This script is not working. Is it because I am still testing using localhost?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule readnews-news_art_id-(.*)\.html$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1
```

Comment: I'm no good with .htaccess, however I have just tested my simple rewrite rules with local host, and they work fine, so no, it's not due to localhost :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks good.
check your server side permissions.
what means do "not working"
do you get an error 500?
if so you probably need to AllowOverride All on that directory in the webserver config.

Comment: Thanks figured it out. I didnt know I had to change my link URls to the nee URLs. Please how can one safeguard .htaccess file? Is it possible to overwrite or delete it by intruders?